# Cookie value not incrementing in PHP

Tags: php, html, cookies

For some reason I'm trying to have my "else" statement increment the amount of times the person has been to my website and it's not incrementing correctly. When I run my php, all it does it increment it once, after that, there are no more refreshes and the $cookieValue just keep echoing 2 instead of 3,4,5,6... What am I missing here?

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('EST');
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["time"])) {
    $cookieValue = 1;
    setcookie("time", $cookieValue, time()+(86400*365));
  }

  $cookieLastVisit = date(DATE_RFC1036);
  setcookie("lastVisit", $cookieLastVisit, time()+(86400*365));
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Question 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if ($cookieValue == 1){
        echo ("Welcome to my webpage! It is the first time that you are here.");
      } else {

        $cookieValue = ++$_COOKIE["time"];

        echo("Hello, this is the " . $_COOKIE["time"]  . " time that you are visiting my webpage. Last time you visited my webpage on: " . $cookieLastVisit . " EST");

        $visit = date(DATE_RFC1036);
        setcookie("lastVisit", $visit);
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how did the value become 2 when the `$cookieValue = ++$_COOKIE["time"];` only applies if the `$cookieValue` is not equal to 1 but the condition `$cookieValue == 1` doesn't have the increment code inside of it?

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac You're right... I actually have no clue. It hops to the else statement upon refreshing the page.

Comment: anyway, just follow Dekel's answer. it works.

Comment: just put `setcookie("time", $cookieValue, time()+(86400*365));` after the echo part.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac It still doesn't work. It increments it once to 2, and then after that every time I refresh the value of $time is just 2, no matter how many times I refresh...

Comment: i tried your code and the answer of Dekel and it works perfectly to me.  maybe there is something wrong with your code. try your code from above and the answer of Dekel on a separate php. Or review your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the setting of the cookie time var to the same place as the declaration.

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('EST');
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["time"])) {
    $cookieValue = 1;
  } else {
    $cookieValue = ++$_COOKIE["time"];
  }
  setcookie("time", $cookieValue, time()+(86400*365));

  $cookieLastVisit = date(DATE_RFC1036);
  setcookie("lastVisit", $cookieLastVisit, time()+(86400*365));
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Question 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if ($cookieValue == 1){
        echo ("Welcome to my webpage! It is the first time that you are here.");
      } else {

        echo("Hello, this is the " . $_COOKIE["time"]  . " time that you are visiting my webpage. Last time you visited my webpage on: " . $cookieLastVisit . " EST");

        // you can't set cookie after you've output to the browser :/
        //$visit = date(DATE_RFC1036);
        //setcookie("lastVisit", $visit);
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of the cookie. The change to the `$_COOKIE` variable doesn't save the value of the cookie in "the next" page

```
else {
    $cookieValue = ++$_COOKIE["time"];
    setcookie("time", $cookieValue, time()+(86400*365));
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, after I constantly reload the page, it still outputs 2 in my else's echo.